nodejs ms2 like table reactive
I would like to show a ms2 like data table refreshing data when changing or just by time interval.
I have seen this nice module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer#reactive-interface
And this even nicer example:
https://github.com/edelciomolina/inquirer-table-input
But I don't want to input data into the table but updating data by interval or just when data change.
Any nice example out there?
Thank you.

Blessed is a library wrapping Curses (a library used to create text user interfaces in the terminal) for Node.js:

Blessed (no longer maintained)
List of resources, with some amaizing examples, like this (1).
Neo-blessed.
React extension.

(1) live example as static .png
